# Send notification when a CloudTrail event occurs for AWS SSO assume role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudtrail

My requirement is to:

1. Trace the log event in cloud trail when a SSO user assumes a
   specific role (developer-full-access) using AWS SSO home page.
2. Send an email notification to a destination that says which SSO user
   has assumed that role.

What is Event Name called when a SSO users assumes a role to login into a specific account? I can see there is a new `IAM` event called `DescribeAccountAttributes` upon user assuming a role, but I am wondering if there is any better event to act upon in this scenario?

Can my requirements be full filled by creating a new `Rule` in `AWS EventBridge` or do I need to have a custom parser running in `Lambda` for example that parse every single event in CloudTrail and filter the ones I am interested?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's break your question in parts:

> What is Event Name called when a SSO users assumes a role to login into a specific account

EventName is  [AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/cloudtrail-integration.html). ( you can verify about this event in cloudtrail -> EventHistory -> EventName(lookup attributes) -> AssumeRole (value)  )

Coming to your requirement

> Trace the log event in cloud trail when a SSO user assumes a specific role (developer-full-access) using AWS SSO home page.
>
> Send an email notification to a destination that says which SSO user has assumed that role.

You will need to [setup cloudwatch alarm for cloudtrail event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-alarms-for-cloudtrail.html) ( in your case assume role)

It would be something like this :-

- Create a metric filter based on Assumerole Event name
- Create an alarm
- Configure SNS as action to alarm whenever alarm is in active
- To that sns topic conjure your email